# Word press Pagination class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagination

I'm adding the class to li if the paged is greater than 9 using Jquery each function, but the class is being added to all the li except for only those li that is greater than 9.
Below is the script I've created but the `console.log("Greater!!");` is working fine.

```
 $( "a.page-numbers" ).each(function( index ) {
 var linum = $(this).attr('href');
 var subStr =  linum.match('[\\d]+');
      console.log(subStr[0]);
      if(subStr[0] >= 10 ){
        console.log("greater!!");
        $(".pagination li a").addClass("circleborder");
        $(".pagination li span").addClass("circleborder");
      } 
});
```

The class circle border is added to all li because I've added it inside each function, but with each function, it is not returning the all li a href.
Console Out is as

```
2
3
20
greater!!
21
greater!!
22
greater!!
```

Comment: Please share HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$(this).addClass("circleborder");
```

Comment: In this pagination function after click the a is converted to span and this class will work but only for few seconds unless it converts to span with current pagination class